# Spring Boot Hibernate Table does not exists

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm creating a Spring boot application with MySQL Database.
I've created an Entity User (normally there is a Table named User when i'm launching the App?)

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    
    private Integer id;
    private String prenom;
    private String nom;
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }
    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    
}
```

I've also an UserRepository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>{

}
```

and the Application.properties

```
spring.jba.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/cashManager21
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

I'm having an error when i'm trying to get data from my DB :
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'cashManager21.User' doesn't exist

Can anyone help me with this error ?

Comment: `User` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. You need to either use a different table name or enable escape chars for table names in hibernate.

Comment: Or add the annotation @Table(name = "\"user\"") to your entity. Maybe have a look at Bootify.io, you can initialize the basic Spring Boot app with entities.

Comment: This might be just a typo? -> spring.jba... should be spring.jpa...

Answer (score 0):

there are two way to solve this issue:--(haha I know only these two, may be there could be more)

**1st:--**

create database (cashManager21) manually.
Excecute below statement in mysql command prompt.

```
CREATE DATABASE cashManager21;
```

**2nd  --**
change database url as below one

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/cashManager21?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Annotate the Entity class with @Table on class level:--

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {       // in log if you see it is searching for (User) not "user" table thats why it is throwing table not found.

blah---
}
```

I would always choose 2nd approach.

**In general:**(FYI)

**Database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.**

Comment: Well, actually i did your 2nd answer and it doesn't work, i'm still having the issue but with CashManager21.user doesn't exist... My database already exists but my table don't

Comment: did you add @Table? in your entity

Comment: can you post full log trace here? Are you running on docker?